# How do I view the "change" addresses in my wallet? listreceivedbyaddress 0 true doesn't work

Tags: transactions, change

I just sent a [test account 5 BTC](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/a6f64058f99b677df9e382c71aa3f04f9205bdafa073f50a2a0533f8cf2aebd9). I see in the output 1.38BTC was "change" and needs to be sent back to my wallet.

Where can I find the contents of `1F39Qj4E3HnbnyYgan5CZa37spGfHro8eK`, and was expecting to find it there, but I typed `listreceivedbyaddress 0 true` and don't see it

Answer (score 1):

The standard client always sends your Bitcoins back to a new address. If you want to figure out which address it went to, you can use `gettransaction` to view your transaction details (you got the ID when you issued the transaction), and check its outputs. The output that is not one of the addresses that you sent money to is your change address.

Comment: I was trying to figure out a wallet-centric way how to get that information... since it should be there right?

Comment: Well, it would be received by an address associated with a given account and it will be part of that given transacion. How more wallet-centric do you need to be?

Comment: So are certain transactions stored / copied into the wallet?  Then that would make sense.

Comment: @makerofthings7 I think all transactions relating to your wallet are stored in the wallet, including double-spends against it.